# How to use varchar datatype as AutoIncrement in Hibernate..?

Tags: hibernate, sql-server-2008, spring-mvc

I am developing a web application with Spring, Hibernate and SqlServer2008. 
For database tables, I am using the auto increment number with int datatype. However, I want to use the varchar datatype as autoincrement.

### for example:

for employee table

EMP1001 ,
EMP1002 ,
EMP1003 ,
... 
...

Thanks...